# ConcurrentBag distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I have a concurrentbag collection that i add items too.. now I may end up with more than one item being the same (defined by 3 string properties being equal)

I am not sure about 2 things.

1. how to generate a hashcode out of 3  properties
2. if converting the concurrengbag to a list then doing a distinct on it using a custom derived comparer is the right way..

Basically the goal is to have cityProcessor property NotFoundCities which may contain duplicates then in the addcities method only get a list of non  dups

```
  public class CityProcesor
{
    public ConcurrentBag<CityNotFound> NotFoundCities { get; set; }
    public void AddCities()
    {
        var nonDups = NotFoundCities.ToList().Distinct(new NotFoundCityComparer());
    }
}
public class CityNotFound
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
public class NotFoundCityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CityNotFound>
{
    public bool Equals(CityNotFound city1, CityNotFound city2)
    {
        return city1.Name == city2.Name && city1.RegionName == city2.RegionName && city1.CountryCode == city2.CountryCode;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(CityNotFound obj)
    {

        return 1; //TODO: fix
    }
}
```

Comment: ConcurrentBag is a *very* specialized collection that uses thread-local storage to ensure each thread gets quick access to the values it created. It's not a concurrent version of a HashSet. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: reason am using concurrentbag is because multiple threads are adding to the same collection

Comment: As I said, that's *not* what it should be used for. When you do a `ToList()` on a ConcurrentBag, you'll get the items created by the calling thread quickly and wait for other items. You can use a ConcurrentDictionary or even a ConcurrentQueue for the scenario you describe. You'd have to override `GetHashCode` in both cases

Comment: I thought concurrentdictionary was to be used if you have a identifier, which I do not have and concurrentbag is the right one as you can stuff anything in there. to be clear, i have multiple threads writing to the bag, once all the threads are done. THEN i try to get that list without dups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you can use the [DistinctBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) extension method from Jon Skeet's [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) which is available either as source code or as a [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=id%3Amorelinq).

With DistinctBy you can write:

```
var noDups=myCities.DistinctBy(city=>
                              new {city.Name,city.RegionName,city.CountryCode});
```

To implement `GetHashCode` inside your comparer, you can use any algorithm that will return a moderately wide-ranged value - it doesn't have to be unique.

The following snippet was created using ReSharper's template and XORs the hashcodes of each property, eg:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (RegionName != null ? RegionName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (CountryCode != null ? CountryCode.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is an awesome extension, thanks i will give that one a try

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for generating hashes. I can't remember where I found the algorithm I based it on (probably somewhere on StackOverflow), but I put it into the following utility class and method to be able to create hashes from multiple fields/properties:

```
public static class HashGenerator
{
    private const int seed = 29;
    private const int factor = 31;

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to generate a hash code from multiple objects.
    /// This can be used when overriding GetHashCode by passing in an object's key fields
    /// </summary>
    public static int GetHashCodeFromMany(params object[] objects)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hashCode = seed;
            int length = objects.Length;
            for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++)
            {
                object obj = objects[counter];
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    int objHashCode = obj.GetHashCode();
                    hashCode *= factor + objHashCode;
                }
            }
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return HashGenerator.GetHashCodeFromMany(Name, RegionName, CountryCode);
}
```

It's best to use this with immutable objects, otherwise changing the key fields/properties can cause havoc with the collection class that's using the hash.